# How use my plugin replace eclipse default console view

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I want to use the browser view to replace the default console view, so that the console can have more extensions.My idea is to force the replacement by implementing the `org.eclipse.ui.console.consolePageParticipants` interface.But it ended up failing because I didn't know how to replace it. I knew that my plan might not be right, but I didn't think of a better solution. Who can provide some ideas.According to my current plan, there is still an unresolved place, how to replace the default console view.

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.console.consolePageParticipants">
    <consolePageParticipant class="me.eclipse.plugin.ansiconsole.participants.AnsiConsolePageParticipant" id="me.eclipse.plugin.ansiconsole.participants.AnsiConsolePageParticipant">
        <enablement>
            <instanceof value="org.eclipse.ui.console.IConsole" />
        </enablement>
    </consolePageParticipant>
</extension>
```

```java
public class AnsiConsolePageParticipant implements IConsolePageParticipant{
    @Override
    public <T> T getAdapter(Class<T> adapter) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void activated() {
        // Nothing to do, but we are forced to implement it for IConsolePageParticipant
    }

    @Override
    public void deactivated() {
        // Nothing to do, but we are forced to implement it for IConsolePageParticipant
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
    }

    @Override
    public void init(IPageBookViewPage page, IConsole console) {
        //do forced replacement
    }
}
```

Comment: That isn't what this extension point is for. I think it would be extremely difficult to do the replacement there as the console view is already setup when this participant is called. In general I think 'replacing the console view' is going to be very difficult. Explain why you think you need to do this.

Comment: Make the console support ANSI. I know there is a plugin for ANSIConsole, but this plugin opens causing eclipse stalls to be delayed. So I plan to develop one myself.